# C Pointer to Pointer via Function

Tags: c

Just playing with pointers, trying to pass the address of a pointer to a function, using:

```
void changer(int **ptr)
{
    if(**ptr==NULL)
    {   
        *ptr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        **ptr=2;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    clrscr();
    changer(&ptr);
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Though the program compiles, the results are not as expected!

Comment: **the results are not as expected!!**  What did you expect? Please provide more info

Comment: What is the intended behavior?  What is it actually doing?  There are several bugs in your code, but without knowing what you wanted to do I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: What in the world is the `clrscr()` function? And what results are you getting? How do those compare to the results that you were expecting?

Comment: getting the output as -21743, clrscr() is used to clear the console (windows)

Comment: Never typecast the result of malloc in C. [Read the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra dereference of `ptr` in the `NULL` check, and you are not initializing the pointer. The program should look like this after the fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changer(int **ptr)
{
    if(*ptr==NULL) // Dereference once, not twice
    {
        *ptr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        **ptr=2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr = 0; // Initialize the pointer
    clrscr();
    changer(&ptr);
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It crashes because you meant on line 3:

```
if (*ptr == NULL)
```

rather than

```
if (**ptr == NULL)
```

You will also want to initialize the pointer to `NULL` on line 13, since you are checking against that with the above:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
```

In C, variables are not automatically initialized to zero, unless allocated at static scope, which has other consequences depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized `ptr` in `main()`, but you check whether what it points to is zero in `changer()`.

Use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changer(int **ptr)
{
    if (*ptr == NULL)
    {
        *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (*ptr != NULL)
           **ptr = 2;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = NULL;
    changer(&ptr);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like another said, you have  an extra *.

I think you can use the fact, that var declaring in c are made from a type, and a expression.

For example, the declare `int **ptr` (if your function), say that the expression `**ptr` is from the type `int`, so in the check `**ptr == NULL`, you compare int to a pointer. It's legal, but when you find yourself doing something like this, you may want to rethink about what you do. (and a good compiler may give you a warning)